# How to define a member function as a delegate in C++/WinRT

Tags: windows, delegates, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

I am trying to define a member function as a delegate for a C++/WinRT component. The component is something that I am trying to build to connect to a BLE device

The idl for the component defines the event as such

```
event Windows.Foundation.EventHandler<UInt32> ConnectNotification;
```

In the consuming app I am able to register a delegate for event's if I define it as a lambda function in this fashion

```
   foundBleNotification = m_bleManager.ConnectNotification([](const auto&, uint32_t foundFlags)
        {
          

            OutputDebugStringW((L"Lambda Called handler->" + hstring(std::to_wstring(foundFlags)) +L"\r\n").c_str());
         
           
           
        });
```

The above works fine and it gets invoked as expected,

However I would like to try and understand how to use a member function for the delegate instead of a lambda function, based on the idl I assumed I could simply define a member function as so...

```
void  BleFound(uint32_t foundFlags);
```

And then register the notification by....

```
foundBleNotification = m_bleManager.ConnectNotification(&MainPage::BleFound };
```

This results in an error that I just cannot figure out :-(

```
Error   C2511   'void winrt::HelloWorldWinRT::implementation::MainPage::BleFound(const winrt::implements<D,winrt::HelloWorldWinRT::MainPage,winrt::composing,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IPageOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IControlOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IControlOverrides6,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IFrameworkElementOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IFrameworkElementOverrides2,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides7,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides8,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::IUIElementOverrides9,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IComponentConnector,winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IComponentConnector2>::IInspectable &,uint32_t)': overloaded member function not found in 'winrt::HelloWorldWinRT::implementation::MainPage' HelloWorldWinRT C:\Users\Jay\source\repos\HelloWorldWinRT\HelloWorldWinRT\MainPage.cpp  66
```

I tried reading up on this here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/weak-references

But that has me even more confused...

Can some experts please point out what I am doing incorrectly and maybe define a member function that would work per the lambda function?

Thanks!

Comment: Member function pointers are only half of the information. You'll also need to pass an instance pointer along. Try `m_bleManager.ConnectNotification({ this, &MainPage::BleFound })` instead.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the suggestion I had to also redefine the member function with the following signature and that took care of the issue  -  void BleFound(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender,
            uint32_t foundFlags);
        I think I am starting to understand the delegate signature a bit better - looks like the template defines it as a function with two parameters the argument I specify and the sender pointer so even though the idl defines it as a function with a single argument, two are expected?? -

Comment: Delegates for general [`EventHandler<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.eventhandler-1) receive two arguments: The `sender` and `args`. The latter can be parameterized. Documentation on templates is inherently poor. [Author events in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-events) has more useful information.